# VLOOKUP formula is working well in the Sheet "AAAA' but not working in Sheet "BBBB'?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have the same data in my two google sheets(Sheet1 name is "AAAA" and Sheet2 name is "BBBB") in spreadsheet1. And I have combined IF,IFERROR and VLOOUP with IMPORTRNGE FORUMLAS for my purpose. IN Sheet "AAAA" the formula works fine but not working in Sheet "BBBB". I have changed sheet 'BBBB' url in a formula. **I have spent so much time to make it correct. I am clueless** . I have attached both sheets. Could i get it correct?

[1]:[SHEET AAAA][1]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13xiSA0hIJx2inhykUSRIi1pqfKJakMTu42Atj9Q-NCM/edit#gid=0

[1]:[SHEET BBBB] [2]
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iecaqixbSuGlAyh_y7uMQkvlPr9q7mhH6RlRDMzUbxI/edit#gid=301923166

Comment: What is wrong? can you give the expected result? For me, everything works fine.

Comment: I have the same impression... as @MikeSteelson . Everything looks the same. Usually these kinds of problems occur when files have no permissions to get data. Formulas are the same, but behavior is different and when IMPORTRANGE is nested inside bigger formula (especially with IFERROR statements), you can't see what type of error it is.

Comment: Excellent sir@KrzysztofDołęgowski.. What you said is 100% correct......Thank you for your response....

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at last...The problem is if we are using the below formula to get information from another spreadsheet ,** Even though you are owner of the sheet**, it won't work in restricted mode. You have to share the sheet with anybody can edit with this link option to get information . **And it doesn't show any error in restricted mode.**
While we are using importrange ,we are clicking the **access option** in that case **sharing option won't make any difference.**

=IF(A1="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KiNMg2pqGqOMtgzKbUNxajTw2eviQTs21Q2jnu5nZ1s/edit#gid=0","Sheet2!$A$2:$C$4"),1,0),"NO SUCH NAME"))